# Problema ao atribuir um ArrayAdapter dentro de um envento OnClick

Tags: java, android, android-studio, mobile

**Método:**

```
spnCondPagamento.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
List listaCondPagamento = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < condPagDao.getListaCondPagamento().size(); i++) {
listaCondPagamento.add(condPagDao.getListaCondPagamento().get(i).getDescricao());
listaIdCondPag.add(condPagDao.getListaCondPagamento().get(i).getId());
}
ArrayAdapter condPagAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item, listaCondPagamento);
condPagAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spnCondPagamento.setAdapter(condPagAdapter);

        }
    });
```

o problema é que está mostrando um `erro`:

> ArrayAdapter condPagAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item, listaCondPagamento);

de unchecked assignment sendo que se assino ele como String da erro ainda

Comment: Você assinou tanto no lado esquerdo quanto no direito? (http://stackoverflow.com/a/4204999/520779)

Comment: Julgo que o problema está na utilização de `this` que neste caso se refere à classe/interface *View.OnClickListener* que não herda de *Context*. Troque `this` por `NomeDaActivity.this`.

Comment: Você tá dentro de um método que está sendo sobrescrito,  tente trocar o 'this' por 'MinhaActivity.this' tente trocar o contexto resumidamente e avise pra gente pensar outra coisa para te ajudar

Comment: erá a assinatura do Contexto, muito obrigado a todos!  Troquei o  this por NomeDaActivity.this